# How can I install Eclipse visual editor?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I downloaded Eclipse visual editor form http://www.eclipse.org/archived/
but when I try to install

```
help > Install New Software > Add > Add Archive
```

when I specified the location of my zip file then shown an error message no software site found.

please help me to install Eclips Visual Editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just uncompress `ve.tgz` and move the `plugins` folder to `your/eclipse/install/path/plugins`.
If you have `features` folder too, move it to `your/eclipse/install/path/features`.
Restart eclipse.